# lists in list comparison with another list

Tags: python, list, comparison, list-comparison

I need to check if  list with lists contains list with similar values to the specified list, values may be in different order but in case all values are same it should return true

```
a= ["1","2","3","4","5"]

b= ["2","3","6","4","7"]

e = (["1","3","2","4","5"],["2","3","6","4","7"])


CombinationFound = []
for i in e:
    if i == a:
        CombinationFound = True
        break;
    else:
        CombinationFound = False
```

it should return true since `["1","2","3","4","5"]` and `["1","3","2","4","5"]` have same values

Comment: Why is `CombinationFound` a list?

Comment: You could use `if i in a:` to check whether the item `i` is in the `a` list.

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert those lists into sets:

```
def isthesame(a,b):
    return set(b) == set(a)
```

For example if you have:

```
a= ["1","2","3","4","5"]
b= ["2","3","6","4","7"]
```

This solution should work for lists that don't have duplicit items.

Comment: `isthesame("cat", "cart")` returns `True`. Is that intentional?

Comment: @Kevin You didn't compare two lists but two strings. Try to use `isthesame(["cat"],["cart"])`

Comment: How about `isthesame([1,2,3], [1,2,3,4,5])`, which also returns `True`?

Comment: The point is that set difference never goes "negative". Non-equal sets can have a zero length difference if the left hand set is a subset of the right hand set. Use the equality operator to see if two sets are equal.

Comment: You're right, the set substraction is position dependent so there's need to check both substractions.

Comment: No, there's no need to check both subtractions. Just use `==`. That's what it's for for sets.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the list you're trying to match against into something you can compare against without caring about the original order. If the number of appearances of an element of the list counts, use sorted lists. If it does not, use sets.

```
list_to_match = sorted(a)
combination_found = False
for i in e:
    if sorted(i) == list_to_match:
        combination_found = True
        break
```

That version will distinguish lists with different numbers of repeated elements - that is, `[0, 1, 1, 2]` will not match `[0, 1, 1, 1, 2]`. If you don't care about that possibility, use `set(a)` and `set(i)` instead:

```
set_to_match = set(a)
combination_found = False
for i in e:
   if set(i) == set_to_match:
       combination_found = True
       break
```

Or, for a more concise version, use the built-in `any` function with a generator expression:

```
list_to_match = sorted(a)
combination_found = any(sorted(i) == list_to_match for i in e)
```

Answer (score 0):

Python [sets](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) are a much better implementation for your particular problem.

Sets are mathematical objects that contain data, but have methods to determine unions, intersections, differences etc between two collections.

Using:

```
set(a) == set(b)
```

should give you the result you want. As long as by 'similar' you mean 'the same'.

Answer (score 0):

Different way to compare without the `for` loop:

```
found = any(set(a)==set(l) for l in e)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def checker(list_of_lists, example):
    for i in list_of_lists:
        if tuple(sorted(i)) == tuple(sorted(example)):
            return True
    return False
```